# What methods of its last estimator does a scikit-learn pipeline have?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scikit-learn-pipeline

I'm trying to understand `scikit-learn` Pipelines.

[According to a Note in the scikit user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#pipeline-chaining-estimators) a Pipeline "has all the methods that the last estimator in the pipeline has".

So I wrote my own estimator class with a method called `myfun`, used an object of this class as the last step in a new Pipeline instance, and called `myfun` on it:

```
class MyEstimator:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def fit(self, X, y):
        return self    
    def myfun(self):
        return None

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
pipe = make_pipeline(MyEstimator())
pipe.myfun()
```

This resulted in the following error message:

```
    pipe.myfun()
    ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'myfun'
```

Evidently contrary to the user guide's claims, a pipeline does not have all the methods that the last estimator in the pipeline has.

So I wonder: what methods (more precisely, method signatures) of its last estimator does a pipeline have?

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html E.g. about subclassing `BaseEstimator`...

Comment: @MattHall: Thanks! It doesn't quite answer my question, but it's a good starting point for further investigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has a subset of the list in the "Methods" section of the [API docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html); the subset is determined by which methods the final estimator has. (It always has some, e.g. those inherited from `BaseEstimator`.)

In the source code, you can identify these methods by the decorator `@available_if`, e.g.

```py
@available_if(_final_estimator_has("predict"))
def predict(...):
```

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/d99b728b3a7952b2111cf5e0cb5d14f92c6f3a80/sklearn/pipeline.py#L483